# Node: convention for public base url

Tags: node.js

With node, I sometimes need to generate absolute urls that point to the public endpoint itself.

It's not always possible to determine that due to proxies and other things.

Is there a convention for specifying the public 'self' endpoint for a node.js server? Any prior art will do, I just want to invent something myself.

Example:

```
cost baseUri = process.env.PUBLIC_URI;
```

Comment: You mean if by default the proxy sends the URL it listens to? Never seen anything like it. Maybe some specific gateways can send it in specific header, but if you are not sure about origin, I would not rely on it.

Comment: What is the problem on passing the base URL from config ENV ?

Comment: @Elia yes, I fully intend to do this via an environment variable. I was just looking to see what a good name for it is. Ideally one that matches what people are already using or matches people's expectation for what this might be called.

Comment: @Evert Ah ok now is more clear. Personally I use `PUBLIC_BASE_URL` I don't know any convention for that.

Comment: @Elia ok sweet. If there's no good answers here I might just adopt that. At least there's one other person out there that uses it ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard convention. An environment variable works just fine whatever it's called. Personally I usually use `process.env.HOST` (which I believe is the equivalent of what you're asking about), because I can then use the [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) library to derive most of the rest of my app config off that.